# SQL Non Clustered Index Design

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

Have a large table T

- `sID Int PK`
- `pos Int PK`
- `wID Int PK`

Self joins

- `T2.sID = T1.sID`
- `T2.pos = T1.pos + 1`
- `T1.wID = 'alpha'`
- `T2.wID = 'beta'`

Added an index on `(wID, sID)` and sure enough it helped (a lot)

In the execution plan noticed the output was sID, pos

So changed the index to `(wID, sID, pos)`.

What surprised me is the query plan stayed the same and no improvement in execution time

So changed the index to `(wID)`

Same query plan and same execution time

Clearly will go with the smaller index for the same performance

My question is why is the smaller index as effective?

Is it because that extra data is the PK?

Comment: Also: if your PK is made up of all three columns, you already **have** a (clustered) index on those three columns (unless you've explicitly turned that off) - just depends on which **order** those columns are defined as in the primary key definition (which you didn't provide.....)

Comment: @marc_s See the PK designation on the three columns.  Yes, listed the PK in order.  The question is the line with the ? mark.